# react-native: Show/hide View by variables in the render instead of states (setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, settimeout

Here is my `render()` method

```
render() {
    let { enableGo } = this.props;
    console.log("value enable go", enableGo);
    let { activeTab } = this.state;
    let toastText;
    let showToast;
    switch (enableGo) {
      case true:
        showToast = true;
        toastText = "Signup Completed!";
        break;
      case false:
        toastText = "Signing up...Please wait";
        showToast = true;
        break;
    }
....
```

I was about to show and hide the `<View/>` based on **enableGo** prop

```
  {showToast && (
              <View
                style={{
                  borderRadius: scale(20),
                  width: scale(150),
                  alignItems: "center",
                  justifyContent: "center",
                  height: verticalScale(25),
                  flexDirection: "row",
                }}
              >
                <Text style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: 12 }}>
                  {toastText}
                </Text>
                {!toastText === "Signup Completed" && (
                  <Spinner color='red' size="small" />
                )}
              </View>
            )}
....
```

I ended up with the `<View/>` not getting hidden after the text gets changed, and the `showToast` becomes `undefined`.

How to make the text changed first, then hide the **View** in a delay?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the showToast variable as you can conditionally render using enableGo only.
Change the text also conditionally using enableGo inside .
wrap the whole View inside another view and place the spinner inside the parent View.
add setInterval for the child View.
I guess that will solve the problem.